# How to resolve gurobipy license/version incompatibility?

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, gurobi

When I run the following code,

```
import pyomo.environ as pe  
pers_solver = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')  
mymodel = pe.ConcreteModel()   
pers_solver.set_instance(mymodel)
```

...I was getting the error `Error message: Version number is 11.0, license is for version 10.0`.  According to this: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/19581700936977

I should do 2 things:

- 1. Check if my python version is compatible.  I'm using python 3.9, which is supported by Gurobi 11.0 according to this: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013195212.
- 2. I should run `pip install gurobipy`.  I ran this and I got "requirement already satisfied".

I checked `/Library/gurobi1100/macos_universal2` and all of the necessary files seem to be there.  So, I clearly have the license.  What do I need to do to get Gurobi to recognize that it's compatible with my current version Python3.9?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, this is a license key issue. You need to update  your gurobi.lic license file.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems I was able to fix that by moving the `.lic` file to the correct location.  However, now I'm faced with an import error: `DeferredImportError: The gurobipy module (an optional Pyomo dependency) failed to import: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gurobipy.gurobipy'` But gurobipy is already installed, as I indicated in my question.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is it something specific to `gurobi_persistent`?